Should I distribute the Mailkit System. dependencies
I'm new to MailKit and I see that it has a number of dependencies named "System.xxx" that are in the NuGet package. (vesrion 4.8.0 - I'm using .net 4.7)
Should I include these in the installer for my project, and if so where should they be installed? (I use Inno Setup)

The System.* assemblies that MimeKit and MailKit depend on need to be installed to the same location as the other assemblies that your installer installs.
